# Redirect links www.mysite.com/whatever-X/whatever-Y/product.html to /product.html

Tags: .htaccess

I work on the platform upgrade of an e-commerce site. The product permalinks are not unique! Each product has a bunch of links, depending on how many categories/subcategories it belongs to. For the same product we have:

www.mysite.com/category1/subcategory1/productuniquename.html
www.mysite.com/category2/subcategory2/productuniquename.html
...

The platform code will be upgraded but we have to make sure that all of the above links from the old platform are redirected to www.mysite.com/productuniquename.html

Is there any .htaccess rule that can handle this redirection? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT:

Tested and is working as expected:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+).html /$3.html [L,R=301]
```

Assumption is made that all files end in html

Comment: looked again and made some changes as well as tested locally

Comment: You will love it! At first for help and then to lend a helping hand.